# Best practices with connecting data from 2 models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got two models: Note and Profile. Note contains foreign key of connected profile as you can see below.

```
Note: {
  profile_id: String,
  date: String,
  content: String,
}

Profile: {
  id: String,
  name: String,
  profilePicture: String

}
```

I want to get all notes and also name and profile picture of note.

In this situation should I:

1. get all notes and all profiles and then join them locally in for loop,
2. get all notes and then in for loop ask DB for name and picture of matching profile,
3. other option

Which way is recomended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [mongoose's Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). You can declare a Schema property with `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'`. When you run a Query you can `.populate()` this field with the corresponding document.